ModuleNotFoundError when importing from engine.py in my Python project
I'm facing an issue with my Python project structure. When I attempt to import a module from engine.py, I encounter a ModuleNotFoundError sqla. I've reviewed my project structure, which you can see in the image linked below. This error has also occurred in another project of mine, and I'm unsure how to resolve it. Any guidance on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


set /sqla to be a package, meaning adding an __init__.py file to it - init.py
Then you can try relative imports so you need to go one level higher to the parent directory:
from ..engine import get_engine


ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I've edited my answer, add an __init__.py file to the directory to make it into a package.

i added before check image

When using import python looks for the module you are trying to import in your active directory. To be able to import get_engine add this code before your import
from sys import path
path.append("path/to/sqla")


why to venv? this my function
anyway i added to result.py
but not worked

Sorry, it shouldn't be to venv but to sqla. I misinterpreted the picture. I will edit my answer accordingly.

idk why dosent work
